How can I get page access token when I have used Instagram API with Instagram Login
I want to be able to use the longLivedToken to publish media to Instagram. Currently, I can only get the containerID but when I try to publish the containerID using the LongLivedToken I'm unable to as I need a page access token. How can I get a Page Access Token when I have used Instagram API with Instagram Login?
I have tried doing make the below request to fetch pages access token but it returns an error
const pageAccessTokenResponse = await axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/me/accounts', {
        params: {
          access_token: longLivedToken
        }
      });

